# To cook a meal for dinner or to cook the meal for dinner?

Tags: articles

To cook a  meal for dinner or to cook the meal for dinner in the sentence like " I cooked the meal for dinner yesterday."? Which one is proper English?

Comment: It depends. If there was a prior question such as "*When was this meal cooked?*", use *the*. If it was "*Did you cook a meal or a whole banquet?*", use *a*. If the only thing you could cook for dinner was a *meal*, consider "*I cooked dinner yesterday.*" (e.g. to "*Who cooked last night?*").

Comment: I don't know how widespread this is, but in my corner of the US the verb paired with dinner to mean "prepare" is almost always *make*: *I **made** dinner last night*. The verb *cook* I would use on its own to mean the same thing: *I **cooked** last night (so it's your turn to make dinner)*.

Comment: I would prefer, for the latter case, "I cooked the dinner meal yesterday,"  which may have a different meaning than that which you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Proper everyday English (one *p*) would just be "To cook dinner".  Dinner is a meal there's redundancy in either of your options.

You could *just about* use the first in some situations:
"We were only going to have leftovers but in the end I cooked **a** meal for dinner yesterday".  It doesn't sound quite natural even then -- I'd probably be more specific ("...in the end I cooked *pizza*...") or rephrase slightly: "We were only going to have leftovers but in the end I cooked *a proper dinner* yesterday".

Comment: You remember I promised to make one of those special kormas sometime this month? I cooked the meal for dinner yesterday. It's a pity you had to stay in Hartlepool.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I had a similar example in mind but *it* would always sound more natural.